# How to automate the wifi login of a captive window?

Tags: macos, automator

I want to automate filling out a WiFi captive portal page on macOSs because I am not asked to save the password.

Only the username gets recorded -- not the password. The "click on the password field" gets recorded but not the input.

How can I determine if this is a limitation in Automator, or the captive window, or the design of the web page when it programmed how the text entry fields are set up?

How can I get the source code of the page from the captive window?

Comment: I've made an pretty big edit here to change this from a  a yes / no question to something more likely to get a good answer. If you want to edit in your script or the browser you use or what macOS version - someone might have another way to automate this if that's something they know will work

Comment: Is filling in the login part of a larger script? Because otherwise, I can't see what Automator gives you that just using MacOS's built-in user and password fill-in doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Deliberately Restricted

Yes, this is a deliberate choice by Apple's engineers. Automator – and other applications – can not intercept keystrokes sent to password fields.

The restriction is enforced by macOS. The keystrokes sent to secure text fields do not appear in the read-only copy of events sent to other observing processes.

### Browsers Using Native Controls

Within a web browser that uses native macOS controls, HTML [password fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password) are represented by a [`NSSecureTextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssecuretextfield).

`NSSecureTextField` deliberately restricts what can see or record its input. The field also limits copying and cutting of the contents.

## Other Approaches

See [How I created a Python Bot to automatically log into a Captive Portal](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-i-created-a-python-bot-to-automatically-log-into-a-captive-portal-3d4ba04dee9f/) or search for [`script wifi login form`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=script+wifi+login+form) for other related projects and tools.

Comment: So - the web designer identifies the field and the web browser / Automator pick up on that classification and decline to enter a value in that field? I'm guessing the proper answer is to use a password manager or store the password in the keychain and get it securely, but maybe that's not what's being asked.

Comment: I would by-pass the browser and send the credentials via the `curl` tool – the WiFi login page will most likely be expecting a form response, which `curl` can handle.

Comment: @bmike its not website or browser but a wifi captive window like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwaGb.jpg)

Comment: @GrahamMiln, but I can not access the login webpage (ip address shown in the captive window) from a browser because I am not connected yet.

Comment: The web traffic is being subverted by the login process. Try the command `curl http://captive.apple.com/cgi-bin/ipdiags.ha' in the Terminal.app. Does it return a page of HTML?

Comment: @GrahamMiln Yes when I am loged in it returns: <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>
W

Comment: When you are logged out, it should return the HTML for the WiFi login page. You can look at the HTML, determine the form elements that match the username/password and then call `curl` with those form elements set, see https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post-file

Comment: @GrahamMiln thanks I got the login page and could use safari to save the credentials. Maybe I just bookmark the login page and run with that :)